# wanted to fetch rows by time increment from mysql table

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table for which i am storing a data of stock quotes received by my feeds. the data looks like table below and have multiple tables and those are having atleast 3M rows in it..

```
id       datetime               size    value
7321798, '2010-12-11 00:00:00',   3,    1384.6
7321799, '2010-12-11 00:00:00',   1,    1384.6
7321800, '2010-12-11 00:00:00',   1,    1384.7
7321801, '2010-12-11 00:00:00',   1,    1384.8
7321802, '2010-12-11 00:00:03',   1,    1384.7
7321803, '2010-12-11 00:00:04',   1,    1384.6
7321804, '2010-12-11 00:00:04',   2,    1384.6
7321805, '2010-12-11 00:00:04',   1,    1384.6
7321806, '2010-12-11 00:00:04',   1,    1384.7
7321807, '2010-12-11 00:00:05',   1,    1384.5
7321808, '2010-12-11 00:00:05',   1,    1384.3
7321809, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   3,    1384.3
7321810, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   2,    1384.3
7321811, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   1,    1384.3
7321812, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   1,    1384.4
7321813, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   1,    1384.5
7321814, '2010-12-11 00:00:06',   4,    1384.6
7321815, '2010-12-11 00:00:07',   1,    1384.6
7321816, '2010-12-11 00:00:07',   5,    1384.6
7321817, '2010-12-11 00:00:08',   1,    1384.6
7321818, '2010-12-11 00:00:09',   3,    1384.7
............
.............
...............
..................
```

now i want total 250 rows in fashion where i can get each row by one minute split and the data for the split would be highest value in the range, lowest value in range and total of column size for that time frame :

so the data fetch should be something like

```
time                   highval  lowval  total of size
2010-12-11 00:00:00     1300     1200    235
2010-12-11 00:01:00     1258     1125    3000
2010-12-11 00:02:00     1440     1312    15000
```

and so on...

(on above result if i request data it will get the highest value, lowestvalue and total (sum) of size column withing 1 minute time frame that is given initially and then continue till total result of rows become 250)

if this can be achieved by single line query its good or please show me the steps to create store procedure for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(datetime,"%Y-%m-%c %H:%i") AS date,
    MAX(value) AS max_value,
    MIN(value) AS min_value,
    SUM(size) AS size_total
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(datetime),HOUR(datetime),MINUTE(datetime)
```

I'm sure other posters will have a more elegant solution but this groups on all time fields from minutes up giving you minute groupings.

Edit:
Grouping by more than one minute and for the last day only could be done by:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(datetime),"%Y-%m-%c %H:%i") AS startDate,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(datetime),"%Y-%m-%c %H:%i") AS endDate,
    MAX(value) AS max_value,
    MIN(value) AS min_value,
    SUM(size) AS size_total
FROM table
WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(datetime),HOUR(datetime),FLOOR(MINUTE(datetime)/2)
```

This makes sure that, for example, minutes 0 and 1 have the same group.
Again, I'm sure other posters may have more elegant solutions.

See the docs on [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for more info on this method.

Comment: From the OP's description, I think {MAX(size)} and {MIN(size)} should be {MAX(value)} and {MIN(value)}.

Comment: let me thank you for your answer jim. i really appreciate that but i need to know that by using same query if i need to get data to be fetched by 2 minutes increment than what are the changes required to existing query. thanks again

Comment: and yes one more thing that the database contains millions of rows so this query execution takes time is there any other efficient way to get the result fast... please help me i m stuck

Comment: @user1278274 Improving the speed is perhaps worthy of a new question. Making sure you use indexes will help however.

Comment: @user1278274 What kind of database are you using?  Have you tried using indexes on this table?  If you know you're always going to have entries for each minute, you can always limit the query to only be for the past 250 minutes: `WHERE DATEADD(mi, -250, GETDATE()) < datetime`.

Comment: i tried it same way by limiting the rows using limit 250 but the performance of the qury is very very slow. hence i ahve only indexed column is ID.. what do you recommend at this level.. please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE DATEADD(mi, -250, GETDATE()) < datetime ... is not working

Comment: where to pplace WHERE DATEADD(mi, -250, GETDATE()) < datetime? could you please update whole query i am little slow in sql

Comment: @user1278274 Added an example for limiting by the last day.